# Rails 3 select checkboxes - pass list to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3 project, I have an index list of `costprojects`.

I have a controller action called `viewprojects'.

I would like to add a checkbox column to the index list. Then let the user select which projects should be included in the pdf.

index:

```
<% @costprojects.each do |costproject| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= check_box_tag "costproject_ids[]", costproject.id %></td>
...
<%= link_to 'PDF Selected', costprojects_viewprojects_path(:format => "pdf",:costproject_ids => costproject_ids[] ), :class => 'btn btn-success', :target => "_blank" %>
```

Controller:

```
 def viewprojects
    @costprojects = params[:costproject_ids]
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render  :pdf => "costprojects.pdf",
                :show_as_html => params[:debug].present?,
                :page_size  => 'letter'
      end
    end
  end
```

I'm getting:

```
undefined local variable or method `costproject_ids'
```

Update1:

Tried:

```
def viewprojects
 @costprojects = params[:costproject_ids[]]
...

<%= link_to 'PDF Selected', costprojects_viewprojects_path(:format => "pdf",:costproject_ids[] => costproject_ids[] ), :class => 'btn btn-success', :target => "_blank" %>
```

I get "wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)"

Do I need to add form_tag and submit_tag?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: params['costproject_ids[]'] try?

Comment: I changed the link_to and the controller to `:costproject_ids[]` and got `wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)`

Comment: Why u use link_to, u can use form with submit input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Legendary mentioned in the comments you need to wrap this in a form. A `link_to` isn't going to transmit the value of the selected ids unless its contained in its query parameters, which it can't know at render time.

Try something more like this:

```
<%= form_tag costprojects_viewprojects_path(format: "pdf") do %>
  <% @costprojects.each do |costproject| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "costproject_ids[]", costproject.id %>    
    </td>
  <% end %>
  ...
  <%= submit_tag "PDF Selected", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

You should then be able to access the array of `cost_project_ids` simply with `params[:cost_project_ids]` in the controller, which it seems you're already doing. Note that this will send an HTTP POST, rather than a GET, so ensure your routes are correctly setup for that verb.

Comment: Thanks!  How would I setup the route? I'm getting `No route matches [POST] "/costprojects/viewproject.pdf"`

Comment: @Reddirt I don't know how your route file is set up, but if you're not using resources or anything like that, then you should simply be able to do something like `post "/costprojects/viewprojects", to: "costprojects#viewprojects`.